# Vim: snipMate plug-in does not trigger snippet completion

Tags: vim, snipmate

[Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) is installed at /usr/share/vim.

All [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540)'s folders were added to this category in existing folders (after, autoload, plugin, snippets, etc.) accordingly.

From the documentation file:

```
For instance, to change the trigger
key to CTRL-J, just change this:

ino <tab> <c-r>=TriggerSnippet()<cr> 
snor <tab> <esc>i<right><c-r>=TriggerSnippet()<cr>

to this: 
ino <c-j> <c-r>=TriggerSnippet()<cr>  
snor <c-j> <esc>i<right><c-r>=TriggerSnippet()<cr>
```

I tried this as well - the same result.
When I try to trigger snippet match it only adds a tab (4 spaces, accordingly to my .vimrc).

P.S. filetype plugin indent on.

**Updated:**

```
cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 9.10
```

:inoremap

```
i  <C-B>       * <C-R>=TriggerSnippet()<CR>
```

:snoremap

```
s  <C-B>       * <Esc>i<Right><C-R>=TriggerSnippet()<CR>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you get when you enter ':inoremap'?  How about ':snoremap'?  Does it show these mappings?

Comment: 2Peter: added. 2 Conspicuous Compiler: yes, it shows these mappings but when you use it - only additional 4 spaces have been added. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running in paste mode (no mappings would work). try :set nopaste

Comment: 2michael: whey I switch to :set nopaste, this shortcut add "^B" instead of 4 spaces. What can it be?

Comment: I'm confused - what key combination do you want to use to trigger snipMate? Have you changed after/plugin/snipMate.vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a problem with snipMate, it wasn't working, so I came across with [Issue 66 in their Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/snipmate/issues/detail?id=66):

```
source ~/.vim/after/plugin/snipMate.vim
```

Comment: `source $VIMRUNTIME/after/plugin/snipMate.vim`

at the end of file C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\plugin\snipMate.vim worked on Windows 7

Comment: @PrayagUpd I'm using newer versions of vim and snipmate, the problem disappeared. Remember that the `source` command has to be called inside a vimrc or gvimrc file, no in terminal.

Comment: I am using gVim 7.4 on Windows. Adding this line works, but everytime I open a file I need to do `:BundleInstall` first, otherwise I get an error telling me that `tlib` is missing.

Comment: @Guus since tlib is a dependency, you can try to call `source` to it's plugin file as well. I'm not having this problem so I can't test for you... :/

Comment: @SomebodystillusesyouMS-DOS I switched from Vundle to Pathogen. And installing Snipmate using Pathogen works for me right away. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 23):

I solved this problem by removing the 'set paste' entry on .vimrc

Comment: I do have a mapping for switching the paste mode, but I did not think of that as a suspect until I saw your post. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Karlisson! That saved me a real headache. To see if paste is the problem, just run :set nopaste from within vi and then see if snipMate's completion starts working. Yay :)

Comment: Ok, but is there a way to get snipMate working with set paste?

Comment: @justin there's a bug report https://code.google.com/p/snipmate/issues/detail?id=111

Comment: If it still doesn't work for someone try - set nopaste

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I experienced the same thing.  SnipMate autocomplete does not work. One of the reasons is the  is used by other plugin. Typing `:verbose imap <Tab>` will show you which plugin that utilizes the  key and cause the conflict. You can either comment out the plugin in .vimrc or you can change it to use another key.

Comment: youcompleteme plugin occupied the tab key, thanks a lot.