# VIm snipmate <TAB> auto completion not working

Tags: vim, snipmate

This is the first time 'm trying **snipmate** with **VIm 7.3** in **ubuntu 12.04**.

### My `.vimrc` [configuration is](https://github.com/iPrayag/.dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc#L44) :

```
" kill vi compatibility
set nocompatible               " be iMproved

" -------------------------------------
" ---------snipmate--------------------
" -------------------------------------
Bundle "MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils"
Bundle "tomtom/tlib_vim"
Bundle "honza/vim-snippets"

Bundle "garbas/vim-snipmate"
" -------------------------------------
 filetype plugin on
```

I believe thats all I want followed by `:BundleInstall`.

The tree structure of my `.vim/bundle` is

```
prayag@prayag:~$ tree -d .vim/bundle/
.vim/bundle/
|-- vim-colors-solarized
|   |-- autoload
|   |-- bitmaps
|   |-- colors
|   `-- doc
|-- vim-snipmate
|   |-- after
|   |   `-- plugin
|   |-- autoload
|   |-- doc
|   |-- ftplugin
|   |-- plugin
|   `-- syntax
|-- vim-snippets
|   |-- UltiSnips
|   |-- autoload
|   `-- snippets
|       |-- coffee
|       `-- javascript
`-- vundle
    |-- after
    |   |-- ftplugin
    |   `-- plugin
    |-- autoload
    |   `-- vundle
    |-- doc
    |-- ftplugin
    |-- plugin
    |-- syntax
    `-- test
        `-- files

139 directories
```

### BUT, when I try some java code to test `main` snippet,

```
$ vi App.java
main
```

After pressing `<TAB>` gives me following result/error

```
main<Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger
```

### `:verbose imap <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger` gives me

```
No mapping found
```

### with `finish` section commented in `plugin/snipMate.vim`, `:verbose imap <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger` gives me following information,

```
i  <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger * <C-R>=snipMate#TriggerSnippet()<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/plugin/snipMate.vim
```

and On pressing `<TAB>`

```
Error detected while processing /home/prayag/.vim/bundle/vundle/autoload/snipMate.vim:                                                                              
line   15:
E122: Function <SNR>84_RemoveSnippet already exists, add ! to replace it
```

### Same result/error I get with following configuration in `.vimrc`,

```
:imap <C-J> <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger
:smap <C-J> <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger
```

*Same configuration worked fine for another **ubuntu 13.04** machine.*

I must be doing something wrong but couldn't figure it out.

### References

[Vim: snipMate plug-in does not trigger snippet completion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3006694/432903)

Comment: What do `:verbose map <TAB>` and `:verbose set cpo?` tell you?  Check `:version` for the "<size> version", where <size> is one of Tiny, Small, Big, Huge (I may be missing some).

Comment: @benjifisher Hi, [here's](https://gist.github.com/iPrayag/5330389#comment-1185495) the result of `:verbose map <TAB>` etc.

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked about `:imap` instead of `:map`.  Probably it will show `i <Tab> <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger`.  What about `:verbose imap <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger`?  It is surprising that the same configuration behaves differently on another machine.  Do you have the same version of snipMate on both?  If not, maybe one is buggy.

Comment: @benjifisher `:verbose imap <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger` gives me `No mapping found`

Comment: That is the problem.  The file https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/blob/master/plugin/snipMate.vim contains the line `inoremap <silent> <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger  <C-R>=snipMate#TriggerSnippet()<CR>`.  Either you do not have that file, it is missing that line, or it is not being `:source`d when vim starts up.  Or maybe the variable `loaded_snips` is defined somewhere else.  Look at the file, check `:scriptnames` right after starting vim, and search for "loaded_snips" in your other startup files.  I guess there are other possibilities, too, like `:imapclear`, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: @benjifisher `:scriptnames` gives me `~/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/after/plugin/snipMate.vim` loaded. Unfortunately that doesn't match to that of [github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/blob/master/plugin/snipMate.vim](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/blob/master/plugin/snipMate.vim)

Comment: You should have similarly-named files in `after/plugin/` and `plugin/` (both relative to `master/` in the GitHub URL's and relative to `~/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/` in your installation).  The "after" version maps `<Tab>` to something starting with `<Plug>`, and the non-"after" version maps that to something else; the second map is the one that seems to be missing.

Comment: @benjifisher Fine, there's a `vim` file at `~/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/plugin/snipMate.vim` similar to https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/blob/master/plugin/snipMate.vim with a line `inoremap <silent> <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger  <C-R>=snipMate#TriggerSnippet()<CR>` .But [HERE's](https://gist.github.com/iPrayag/5330389/#comment-1188316) my `after/plugin/snipMate.vim`

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with the file in your `after/plugin/` directory, do you?  I gave several things to check 4 comments ago:  now that you know that you have the right file in the `plugin/` directory, check that it is being sourced with `:scriptnames`.  If it is, then either `loaded_snips` is defined somewhere else (easy to test by commenting out the `finish` line in the plugin) or the mapping is being removed later.

Comment: @benjifisher Thanks. After commenting out `finish` line in the plugin threw `Error detected while processing /home/prayag/.vim/bundle/vundle/autoload/snipMate.vim`. I removed this file along with `vim-snipmate` and reinstalled. Working fine. Please post your comments as answer. \,,/

Comment: Hi, @PrayagUpd, what operating system were you using? I think I have encountered exactly the same problem on my Windows 8.2 machine; however, using exactly the same set of packages, and similar vimrc, the `<tab>` key should have been working well on my Mac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I suggest that you remove `:set nocompatible` from your vimrc file.  Vim automatically resets the `'cp'` option if it finds a personal vimrc file (not a system vimrc file) on startup, and if you ever `:source ~/.vimrc` then it can have confusing results.

A complete answer to your question would be a very large troubleshooting flowchart.  That would be a good thing to have, but I am not going to work that hard.  Here is a summary of the conversation we had in the comments to diagnose this problem.

> I have [snipMate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) installed, but when I enter `"main<Tab>"` in Insert mode, I get `"main<Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger"`.

What do `:verbose imap <Tab>` and `:verbose set cpo?` tell you? Check `:version` for the "<size> version", where <size> is one of Tiny, Small, Big, Huge (I may be missing some).  (The problem may be how `<Tab>` is mapped, or you may be in compatible mode, or your version of vim may not support maps or may not support the `<Tab>` notation in maps.)

> `":verbose imap <Tab>"` shows that "`<Tab>"` is mapped to `"<Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger"` in `"~/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/after/plugin/snipMate.vim"`, and the other stuff looks right.

How about `:verbose imap <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger`?  (The problem seems to be that `<Tab>` is mapped to something; that something is supposed to be remapped, but it is not.)

> `":verbose imap <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger"` gives me "No mapping found".

That is the problem. The file [plugin/snipMate.vim](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/blob/master/plugin/snipMate.vim) contains the line `inoremap <silent> <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger  <C-R>=snipMate#TriggerSnippet()<CR>`. Either you do not have that file, it is missing that line, or it is not being `:source`d when vim starts up. Or maybe the variable `loaded_snips` is defined somewhere else. Look at the file, check `:scriptnames` right after starting vim, and search for "loaded_snips" in your other startup files. I guess there are other possibilities, too, like `:imapclear`, but that seems unlikely.

> The file is there, and has the right line.  (At first I looked at "after/plugin/snipMate.vim" instead of "plugin/snipMate.vim".)  I checked ":scriptnames" and it is listed.  I did not check for other files defining "loaded_snips", but I commented out

```
if exists('loaded_snips') || &cp || version < 700
    finish
endif
```

> and got an error from "snipMate.vim" in *another* directory.  I removed that file, re-installed snipMate, and now it works.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. For me the problem was that a random, old, unused line from my vimrc was overriding the tab mapping. `:verbose imap <Tab>` revealed it, and removing it allowed me to start using